# Тень в ячейке Table View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Внутри contentView ячейки таблицы есть UIImageView с отступами по 15 поинтов. У этого UIImageView свойство layer.masksToBounds = true.

Вот такая функция создает тень:

```
func createDefaultShadow(for view: UIView) {
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0

    clipsToBounds = false
    layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Когда я передаю в параметр view UIImageView, тень не отображается, но если передать туда contentView, тогда создается тень вокруг UIImageView, как мне и надо.

Почему это работает таким образом? Разве это не должно работать наоборот? Для наглядности прикреплю изображение. [image: Ячейка]

Код в ячейке:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    createDefaultShadow(for: contentView)
    poster.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Вы говорите, что у вас layer.masksToBounds = true а в коде false. В какой момент вы тень добавляете? При кофигурировании ячейки?

Comment: @Vitaly да, тень добавляется в методе awakeFromNib(). Добавил код в конец поста. Poster – UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
func createDefaultShadow(for myView: UIView) {
    myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    myView.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0

    myView.clipsToBounds = false
    myView.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению такой подход не работает.